# Providers is null in nextauth

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next-auth, next.js13

This is my first project at nextjs. i was using NextAuth  and googleprovider for authentication... i am getting the next-auth client fetch error and also 404 error for server on the console.

app/api/auth/...nextauth/route.js

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google';

import User from '@models/user';
import { connectToDB } from '@utils/database';

const handler = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    })
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session }) {
      // store the user id from MongoDB to session
      const sessionUser = await User.findOne({ email: session.user.email });
      session.user.id = sessionUser._id.toString();

      return session;
    },
    async signIn({ account, profile, user, credentials }) {
      try {
        await connectToDB();

        // check if user already exists
        const userExists = await User.findOne({ email: profile.email });

        // if not, create a new document and save user in MongoDB
        if (!userExists) {
          await User.create({
            email: profile.email,
            username: profile.name.replace(" ", "").toLowerCase(),
            image: profile.picture,
          });
        }

        return true
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error checking if user exists: ", error.message);
        return false
      }
    },
  }
})

export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

nav component

```
const { data: session } = useSession();

  const [providers, setProviders] = useState(null);
  const [toggleDropdown, setToggleDropdown] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const res = await getProviders();
      setProviders(res);
    })();
  }, []);
```

```
<>
            {providers &&
              Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                <button
                  type='button'
                  key={provider.name}
                  onClick={() => {
                    signIn(provider.id);
                  }}
                  className='black_btn'
                >
                  Sign in
                </button>
              ))}
          </>
```

here the providers is null and i am not able to render the sign in button but from the tutorial i am following they seem to get the sign in button..

i have double checked my environment variables too and they are all right. dont know whats the problem.

i have double checked my environment variables too and they are all right. dont know whats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your route.js in API folder.

In my case was:

```
provider: [
    GoogleProvider(
```

And should be:

```
providers: [
    GoogleProvider(
```

I forgot to put 's' in providers

Comment: Could you please fix the formatting of your answer. It's difficult to distinguish between code and text.

Answer (score 0):

Please update your folder name As like this
`app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js`